# Analytically Evaluating the Inverse Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

How should I go about trying to solve this particular inverse F.T.:

$$
\mathcal G(f) = e^{\frac{-(f-f_0)^2}{(2\sigma)^2}}
$$

From the definition of the continuous inverse F.T.

$$
\mathcal{F^{-1}} [G(f)] = g(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (e^{j2\pi ft})G(f) df
$$

I'm somewhat grasping the forward direction of going from time to frequency domains but it's a little more difficult for me to go the other way. It looks like a frequency shift to me but the $(2\sigma)^2$ is throwing me off.

I mistakenly took it as a Gaussian in the time domain, any help or advice on tackling this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\mathcal{F}^{-1} \{G(f)\} = g(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm e^{j2\pi ft}\,G(f) \,\mathrm df= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm e^{j2\pi ft-\frac{(f-f_0)^2}{(2\sigma)^2}} \,\mathrm df
$$
Completing the square 
$$
\begin{align}
j2\pi ft-\frac{(f-f_0)^2}{4\sigma^2}&=-\frac{f_0^2-(4 j \pi t \sigma^2 + f_0)^2}{4\sigma^2}-\frac{[f -(4 j \pi t \sigma^2 + f_0)]^2}{4 σ^2}\\
&=j (4 \pi^2 j \sigma^2 t^2 + 2 \pi f_0 t)-\frac{[f -(4 j \pi t \sigma^2 + f_0)]^2}{4 \sigma^2}
\end{align}
$$

then we have
$$
\begin{align}
g(t) &= \mathrm e^{j (4 \pi^2 j \sigma^2 t^2 + 2 \pi f_0 t)} \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left(-\frac{[f -(4 j \pi t \sigma^2 + f_0)]^2}{4 \sigma^2}\right) \,\mathrm df}_{\sqrt{\pi}\,2\sigma}\\
&=\sqrt{\pi}\,2\sigma\,\mathrm e^{j (4 \pi^2 j \sigma^2 t^2 + 2 \pi f_0 t)} 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You can't use a complex change of variable without discussing it